# Modify Debug Console Auto Completion

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

When debugging js for a web application, the autocomplete in the Debug Console is drawing it's choices from a js library, not the script being debugged.  Is there a way to change its behavior to mimic Chrome Dev Tools?
Thanks.